# About simple thermalization simulation: why the final distribution is not $E^{2}\exp[-E/T]$ but $E\exp[-E/T]$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, simulations

I made a simulation that studies the thermalization of massless particles, assuming isotropic and homogeneous spatial distribution, in 3 dimensions. Namely,

1. I started with $N$ particles having random distribution in energy $E$ and isotropic directions.
2. Next, I assumed that they meet at one point (so I drop any spatial coordinates from the exercise) and randomly chose their pairs, assuming the probability of selecting each pair is pair-independent and equal to $2/N(N-1)$.
3. Then, I generated collision kinematics: I boosted to the CM frame, and generated random polar (assuming that $\cos(\theta)$ is uniformly distributed from -1 to 1, which is true in the case of a constant matrix element of the process) and azimuthal scattering angles (simply from $-\pi$ to $\pi$), and boosted back.
4. I repeat these steps (now remembering the directions) many times.

I expected the final energy distribution of the particles to follow the scaling $E^{2}\exp[-E/T]$, where $T$ is the effective temperature of the system determined from $N$ and the total energy. $E^{2}$ comes from the Liouville theorem: the density of states in a D-dimensional space is $d^{n}\mathbf{p} \propto E^{n-1}dE$. However, I got $E\exp[-E/T]$. When repeating the same exercise for the 2D case, I got $\exp[-E/T]$ instead of $E\exp[-E/T]$.

So it looks like I missed some important point, which leads to the reduction of the dimensionality by one. What may be the reason for this?

**Simulation example**

Below, there is an example of the simulation for the 3D case and identical pairing probabilities - the histogram distribution of the initial state (yellow bars), the final state (blue bars), as well as fits of the distributions $E^{n}\exp[-E/T]$ with $n = 0$ (the blue curve), $n = 1$ (the red one), $n = 2$ (the green one). For the initial distribution, I simply took $E^{2}\exp[-E/T]$:

[image]

It is clearly visible that the interactions turn the distribution from $E^{2}\exp[-E/T]$ to $E\exp[-E/\tilde{T}]$.

Also, the results do not depend on $N$ or the number of simulated steps. The system quickly falls to this "equilibrium" state, which seems like an intrinsic property of the pairing and interactions.

Comment: Now that my results agree with yours, I'm not sure what could be going wrong.  Possibilities include:  errors in the collision algorithm (incorrectly distributed polar angles? failure to transform the collisions back into the lab frame?); improper binning techniques (make sure they're all of the same width in $E$);  insufficient data to distinguish the exponent of $E$ in the density of states to a sufficient resolution.  Without more information about the simulation I'm not sure this can be answered here.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : I have added the plots showing the initial and final distributions, please see the updates to my question; the binning is for constant bin widths, and the amount of particles is enough to distinguish the behavior of the low-energy tail. I also checked that the 4-momentum is conserved in the collision (in particular, the total final energy is equal to the total initial energy, and the total momentum $\to 0$), as well as verified that the final particles have isotropy in directions.

Comment: Why is your probability to choose a pair $1/N$ and not $2/N/(N-1)$? For the second simulation, are you using $p_1\cdot p_2$ to bias the choice the of pair which is not uniform anymore, or are you still choosing uniformly the pair and use it to bias the outcome of the collision which is not isotropic anymore?

Comment: @LPZ : overall, I mean that the probability does not depend on the specific pair, it is constant. For the given particle, the probability of pairing with the rest of the particles is $1/(N-1)$ (and not $1/N$ as I wrote). If considering all the N particles, you are correct that the probability is $2/N(N-1)$. I will clarify this point, thanks! For the second simulation, I still sample directions uniformly, but when selecting the pairs I associate the weight $\propto 1/(p_{1}\cdot p_{2})$ to each of the pair.

Comment: Ok, and out of curiosity (doing the simulations myself), what did you choose for $N$ and how many collisions did you simulate?

Comment: @LPZ : I started with a simple simulation that assumes that per each timestep all particles must interact. The results do not depend on the number $N$ (after reaching some threshold $N = N_{\text{max}}$) and on the number of simulated interactions $n$ (after reaching some threshold $n = n_{\text{max}}(N)$. For the plots, I considered $N = 4000$ and $n = 20$.

Comment: Have you tried bigger N and n? Maybe you should first check that your lineshape doesn't vary with bigger or smaller N and n.

Comment: According to the principle of detailed balance, equilibrium result shouldn't depend on the form of your interaction as long as it sustain channels between every pair in the phase space. Sometimes the balance can't be achieved and you thermalize in some unintuitive subspace. The histogram looks pretty rough, Maybe try N=40000 n=200 that shouldn't be too demanding for your PC

Comment: @Bababeluma : I checked it previously. Independently of the number of particles, the system ends up in this state.

Comment: @NameYYY interesting

Answer (score 6):

*Below is my confirmation that the distribution should be proportional to $E^{n-1} e^{-E/kT}$.  I originally did these calculations for massive particles, which lead to a different result than what the OP was expecting, and so I posted it as an answer.  However, since my results now agree with the OP's, this no longer constitutes a possible answer, and I don't know what's going on.*

---

The Boltzmann distribution in momentum space for massless particles in $n$ dimensions is
$$
f(\vec{p}) \, d^n\vec{p} \propto e^{-\beta c p}  \, d^n\vec{p},
$$
with $\beta = 1/kT$.
To transform this into a distribution with respect to energy, we change to polar coordinates in momentum space, in which
$$
d^n \vec{p} = p^{n-1} \, dp \, d\Omega_p
$$
with $d \Omega_p$ representing the solid angle in velocity space.  Integrating over solid angle just yields a constant that can be folded into the normalization, so the distribution with respect to speeds is
$$
f(p) \, dp \propto p^{n-1} e^{-\beta cp} \, dp
$$
Finally, to transform this into a distribution with respect to energy, we note that $p = E/c$ and so $dp = dE/c$; and thus
$$
f(E) \, dE \propto E^{n-1} e^{-\beta E} \, dE.
$$
Thus, the distribution should be $f(E) \propto E^2 e^{-E/kT}$ in 3D and $f(E) \propto E e^{-E/kT}$ in 2D.

Comment: Thanks, but I am studying massless particles.

Comment: I missed that!  Let me modify things appropriately.

Comment: Pure speculation, but could it be related to needing to use a relativistically invariant measure? The Lorentz invariant measure in QFT is (up to factors of $2\pi$) is $d^3 k / \omega_k$, so maybe that factor of $1/\hbar \omega \sim 1/E$ accounts for the power of $E$ being one less than expected?

Comment: @Andrew : because of some reason, if I introduce some specific weights for pairing, I then recover a pure Boltzmann exponent. The weight may or may not break the Lorentz invariance.

Comment: @Andrew that measure is for convenience since the creation operator also has a special normalization.

Comment: For non-relativistic particles, I recover the desired shape (please see the update to my question).

Comment: I agree with Andrew. If the integrand is a scalar, then the measure should be $d^3k/E_k$.

Comment: @NameYYY I don't exactly know what you mean in the last sentence: Independent of weights (i.e. did you try it out with arbitrary, completely unphysical weights or just whether or not 1/E does anything), but if it's the latter, it doesn't rule out Andrews explanation.

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 : I checked with arbitrary weights.

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 : also, there should not be any dependence on the integrand//matrix element (only in the sense that the system thermalizes for a longer period of time).

Comment: @NameYYY I'm guessing because changing weights is equivalent to changing the initial distribution and thus the thermalized state would "forget" about this. However, what does change would be how you read out the final distribution no? Because you are essentially always reading out weight x distribution. But if you forget about the appropriate weight, you also don't only get the distribution, but also times the weight, thus accounting for the factor of 1/E

Comment: To be fair, I'm reaching well out of my comfort zone here. I just wanted to refute Bababeluma's statement and note that Andrews complaint is justified (even if this may not be relevant to the problem at hand.)

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 : why do you yhink thst changingnweights is identical to changing the initial distribution? The weights determine the interacrion of the system at each step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151972/discussion-between-confuse-ray30-and-name-yyy).

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 : please see the last update to my question.

Comment: @NameYYY I saw your last update. I don't think I can be much of help anymore unfortunately, since I am by no means someone who does simulations. You already understood the physical principles needed to make this work. How these enter the results explicitly, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my simulation is a simplified version of the direct simulation Monte Carlo approach (DSMC), where I restrict myself to one "particle cell". Some relevant discussions are provided in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.1762.pdf); in particular, see Fig. 1 and the text around. In short, using the unit pairing weight would violate the Lorentz invariance and directly lead to the shape $\propto E\exp[-E/T]$ I got previously. So, I included the pairing weight
$$
P \propto \sigma\cdot v\cdot (1-\mathbf{v}_{1}\cdot \mathbf{v}_{2}) = \frac{\sigma \cdot s}{2E_{1}E_{2}},
$$
where
$$
v = \frac{p_{1}\cdot p_{2}}{E_{1}E_{2}(1-\mathbf{v}_{1}\cdot \mathbf{v}_{2})}
$$
is the relative velocity, and $s$ is the invariant mass of the colliding pair.

For the particular choice $\sigma = f(s)$, I recovered the correct distribution (the plot assumes $f(s) =\text{const}$):

[image]

I would immediately break this scaling, if I include any Lorentz invariance breaking factors in the weight.